# Django-taggit adding new tags to an object?

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

My models.py

```
class X(models.Model):
...
tags = TaggableManager()
```

How to add tags to an object. If I do:

```
 x = X.objects.get(pk = 123)
 x.tags.add( "sample_tag" )
```

It adds the tag twice, if the tag with same name (i.e "sample_tag" in the above in the case) has been previously created.
Now when I retrieve tags :

```
>>> x.tags.all()
>>> [<Tag: sampletag>, <Tag: Sample_tag>]
```

How to do solve this problem. I want to add a new tag only if its not created before, and if created just refer the  new object to that tag?

Comment: Why aren't you just using `X.tags.add( "tag" )`?

Comment: I want to add `"tag"` to a particular instance of the class, not to the class? or do i?

Answer (score 4):

django-taggit does exactly what you want, but in your case `sampletag` != `Sample_tag`, so another `Tag` instance is created.

```
>>> i.tags.all()
[]
>>> i.tags.add("test")
>>> i.tags.all()
[<Tag: test>]
>>> i.tags.add("test")
>>> i.tags.all()
[<Tag: test>]
>>>
```